# Visual Studio Customize What gets Outlined

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I just upgraded to VS2017, and I'm having issues with the Code Outlining. Specifically, I want methods, regions, classes to stay outlined and collapse/expand as they did in VS2015, but I don't want if/for and other code blocks to be outlined. I want them to always be expanded.
Anybody know how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I found it myself in the settings.
In the Menu bar, Go to Tools->Options, then follow the trail in the image below to get the fix.

[VS Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8DPj.png)

(I don't have enough reputation to post the image, so the link goes to it. If you don't want to go there, it's Tools->Options, then Text Editor->C#->Advanced and uncheck "Show outlining for code level constructs")

Comment: And for those searching for how to avoid collapsing strings (as well as other areas of code), I can very much recommend this. By default, collapsing code appears to be enabled.